# Problema al hacer dos clicks seguidos en un gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Tengo una aplicación web (en asp.net) que me está volviendo loco.
Me muestra en un Gridview los ficheros contenidos en una ruta que está alojada en un servidor de Sharepoint. El caso es que funciona bien, excepto por un pequeño problemas que os paso a detallar a ver si os suena...

El caso es que entro en una carpeta, y en el Gridview me muestra todas las carpetas y ficheros que haya. La estructura de lo que muestra es un icono que viene determinado por el tipo de fichero que es, el nombre y un icono que aparece si nunca lo he descargado.
Pulsando en el primer icono de la línea, descargaría el fichero en caso de ser un fichero y si fuera una carpeta pues se accede a dicha carpeta y luego lo mostraría el gridview.

En este último punto es donde viene el problema. Si pulso sobre una carpeta una vez y antes de que se actualize el gridview, pulso una segunda vez, resulta que me descarga el fichero que debería aparecer en dicha posición y además el gridview no se actualiza.

¿Se os ocurre que puede estar pasando?

El código de mi gridview es el siguiente

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetalleFicheros" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%" CssClass="gv-fuente-informe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" OnRowCommand="gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand" >
                        
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBt" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Imagenes/"+ Eval("Imagen") %>' Height="40" Width="40" CommandName ="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'> </asp:ImageButton>                                             
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbFichero" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID ="lbTipo" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# (bool)Eval("IsFolder") ? "Carpeta" : "Archivo" %>' > </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbRutaCompleta" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Names="Arial" Text='<%#Eval("Url")%>' ></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Visible="false" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' >Descargar</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Image ID="lbImgLeido" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Imagenes/"+ Eval("Leido") %>' Height="30" Width="30" Visible='<%# (string)Eval("Leido")=="nuevo.png" %>'></asp:Image>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Todo mi código cs, correspondiente

```html
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;


namespace AplicacionVendedores
{
    public partial class DocumentosAgro : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DatosEntrada Entrada;
        FicherosSharepoint oFichero;

        // Parámetros configuración
        private string RutaBase = "miruta/Intranet"; 
        private bool LeerDirectorios = true;
        private bool ControlLeidos = false;
        private bool CargarBBDD = false;
        private bool ControlPermisos = false;

        public string RutRelativa = "/";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["DatosEntrada"] != null)
            {
                Entrada = (DatosEntrada)HttpContext.Current.Session["DatosEntrada"];
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!FunComunes.TienePermisosSeccion((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["PermisosUsuario"], Request.Path.Replace(Request.ApplicationPath, "")))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Inicio.aspx");
            }

            oFichero = new FicherosSharepoint(this.RutaBase,
                                    this.LeerDirectorios,
                                    this.ControlLeidos,
                                    this.CargarBBDD,
                                    this.ControlPermisos,
                                    Entrada.NifVendedor,
                                    FicherosSharepoint.OrdenFecha);

            GlobalClass.ComprobarPermisosCarpetasSharepoint = false; 

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // Se registra en el log el acceso a esta sección
                AccesoDatos.RegistrarLog(Entrada.NifVendedor,
                                        Request.Path.Replace(Request.ApplicationPath, ""),
                                        Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.Version,
                                        Request.Browser.Platform);

                VaciarExcesoProfundidad(-1);
                GlobalClass.profundidadDir = 0;
                GlobalClass.directorio[GlobalClass.profundidadDir] = "/";
                
                CargarDetalleFicheros();
            }
            
        }
        protected void btnVolver_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Clientes");
        }


        private void CargarDetalleFicheros()
        {
            #region lectura directorio
            BindGridView(this.RutRelativa);

            // Se configura la botonera de navegación por directorios
            InicializarBotoneraNavegacion();
            EstablecerBotonesNavegacion(GlobalClass.directorio);

            if (gvDetalleFicheros.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                gvDetalleFicheros.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gvDetalleFicheros.Visible = false;
            }
            GlobalClass.clicksharepoint = false;//18/10/2023
            #endregion
        }

        protected void btnDir_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string idBt = "BtDir";
            string Ruta = "";
            int i = 0;

            // Averiguamos qué botón se ha pulsado y se va contruyendo la ruta
            Button bt = (Button)sender;

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //lo cambio a 10 y habia un 7
            {
                Button bt2 = (Button)phTitulo.FindControl(idBt + i.ToString());
                if ((GlobalClass.directorio[i].Length > 0) && (i > 1))
                {
                    Ruta += "/" + GlobalClass.directorio[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Ruta += GlobalClass.directorio[i];
                }

                if (bt.ID.Equals(idBt + i.ToString()))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            GlobalClass.profundidadDir = i;
            this.RutRelativa = Ruta;
            VaciarExcesoProfundidad(GlobalClass.profundidadDir);
            CargarDetalleFicheros();
        }
        protected void VaciarExcesoProfundidad(int maximo)
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = maximo + 1; i < GlobalClass.directorio.Length; i++)
            {
                GlobalClass.directorio[i] = "";
            }
        }

        private void InicializarBotoneraNavegacion()
        {
            BtDir0.Visible = false;
            BtDir1.Visible = false;
            BtDir2.Visible = false;
            BtDir3.Visible = false;
            BtDir4.Visible = false;
            BtDir5.Visible = false;
            BtDir6.Visible = false;
            BtDir7.Visible = false;
            BtDir8.Visible = false;
            BtDir9.Visible = false;
        }

        private void EstablecerBotonesNavegacion(string[] directorios)
        {
            int count = 0;

            if (directorios != null && directorios.Length < 10)
            {
                foreach (string dir in directorios)
                {
                    if (dir.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Button bt = (Button)phTitulo.FindControl("BtDir" + count.ToString());
                        if (bt != null)
                        {
                            bt.Text = dir.ToString();
                            if (bt.Text == "/")
                            {
                                bt.Text = "Agro";
                            }
                            bt.ToolTip = "";
                            bt.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        public void EstablecerRuta(string Ruta)
        {
            
            //21/03/2023 Coloco este if 
            if ((GlobalClass.profundidadDir > 0) && (Ruta == ""))
            {
                GlobalClass.directorio[GlobalClass.profundidadDir] = Ruta;
                GlobalClass.profundidadDir -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                GlobalClass.profundidadDir += 1;
                GlobalClass.directorio[GlobalClass.profundidadDir] = Ruta;// selectedFile.Name;
            }

            this.RutRelativa = "";
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < GlobalClass.directorio.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((GlobalClass.directorio[i].Length > 0) && (i > 0))
                {
                    this.RutRelativa += "/" + GlobalClass.directorio[i];
                }
            }
        }

        public void RegistrarFicheroLeido(string fichero, string userIntranet)
        {
            string sSQL = "update tbZPControlLeidos set dLeido = getdate() where usuario ='" + userIntranet + "' and Archivo = '" + fichero + "'";
            FunComunes.EjecutarConsulta(sSQL);
        }

        protected void gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
             if (GlobalClass.clicksharepoint)
             {
              return;
             }
            try { 
            if (e.CommandName == "Select") //View
            {
                var index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                var filesAndFolders = Session["FilesAndFolders"] as List<SharepointFile>;
                var selectedFile = filesAndFolders[index];
                GlobalClass.clicksharepoint = true;
                if (selectedFile.IsFolder)
                {
                    EstablecerRuta(selectedFile.Name);
                    CargarDetalleFicheros();
                }
                else
                {
                    var siteUrl = "XXXXXXXX";
                    var userName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    var password = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
                    
                    using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
                    {
                        var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
                        foreach (char c in password)
                        {
                            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                        }
                        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

                        var web = context.Web;
                        var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(selectedFile.Url);
                        var stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        var buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int bytesRead;
                        var ms = new MemoryStream();
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                        // Get the file extension
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(selectedFile.Name);

                        try
                        {
                            // Set the content type based on the file extension
                            Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(extension);

                            // Set the content disposition header
                            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + selectedFile.Name);

                            // Write the file to the response
                            Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
                            Response.Flush();
                            Response.Close();
                            // End the response
                            //Response.End();
                            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

                            //22/03/2023  Registramos la descarga
                            AccesoDatos.RegistrarLog(Entrada.NifVendedor,
                                        "Descarga fichero " + selectedFile.Url,
                                        Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.Version,
                                        Request.Browser.Platform);

                            RegistrarFicheroLeido(selectedFile.Url, Entrada.NifVendedor);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AccesoDatos.RegistrarLog(Entrada.NifVendedor, ex.Message.ToString() + " Documentos Agro.", Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.Version, "LOGSHARE");
                return;
            }
        }

        private void BindGridView(string folderUrl)
        {
            
            var siteUrl = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
            var userName = "XXXXXXXX";
            var password = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            var libraryName = "Site Pages";

            var folderServerRelativeUrl = $"miruta{folderUrl}";
            var sharepointFolderManager = new SharepointFolderManager();

            var filesAndFolders = sharepointFolderManager.GetFilesAndFolders(siteUrl, userName, password, libraryName, folderServerRelativeUrl, Entrada.NifVendedor, true);
            Session["FilesAndFolders"] = filesAndFolders;

            gvDetalleFicheros.DataSource = filesAndFolders;
            gvDetalleFicheros.DataBind();
            
        }
    }
}
```

He probado con un flag pero que he añadido nuevamente para explicar a ver si me podéis echar un cable con lo que esté haciendo mal. Tengo una variable global Glogalclass.clicksharepoint de tipo Bool. He añadido las líneas donde he colocado la variable.

En CargarDetalleFicheros es donde se pone clickshare a false, y en el procedimiento gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand es donde al principio si es True, salgo y no hago nada; y si es false coloco la variable a true y hago lo que tenga que hacer.

El problema es que cuando hago el segundo click, el programa antes de entrar en gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand termina con el prodecimiento CargarDetalleFicheros el cual vuelve a poner clickshare a false, de forma que cuando de nuevo salta al procedimiento gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand la variable no está a true sino a false, haciendo de nuevo el procedimiento. Es más, la pantalla no ha refrescado y en la posición del segundo click, ya corresponde a un fichero y directamente me lo descarga en vez de entrar en la carpeta por poner un ejemplo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Está pasando que no estás controlando los clicks de manera correcta. Primero que nada, para preguntar en SO es necesario incluir el código relevante, no podemos responderte a algo "adivinando" lo que has hecho, y las preguntas basadas en opiniones o adivinaciones no son válidas aquí. Se pregunta y se responde sobre hechos concretos! Segundo, si tienes un botón que cambia de funcionalidad tras hacer X consulta, lo lógico es que tras el primer click LO DESHABILITES HASTA QUE TERMINE LA CONSULTA. Así no tienes problemas con dobles clicks, pues lo primero que haces al detectar uno es deshabilitar!

Comment: Lo primero, muchas gracias por contestar. He añadido el código... Con respecto a la funcionalidad, no tengo un botón sino que hago click sobre la línea en cuestión sobre el gridview, en concreto sobre el ImageButton que es la columna de mi gridview sobre la que puedo hacer click realmente. ¿Sería posible deshabilitar esa columna nada más? Os agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda, ya que llevo un par de días y no consigo dar con la solución.

Comment: No necesitas deshabilitar una columna concreta, puedes simplementer tener un flag `loading = true; y nada más entrar al método que gestiona ese click un if sencillo: `if (loading) return;` y ya está. Simplemente acuérdate de poner el flag a false cuando termines de cargar los datos. Si quieres que sea por línea puedes usar el mismo flag pero también deberías guardar la línea en la que se hizo el clic y comprobar si es la misma. Hay mil soluciones, esta es la que me parece más sencilla.

Comment: Lo de la variable global ya lo había probado no obstante lo he añadido al código que he puesto antes para que lo podáis ver, así como la explicación de lo que ocurre ya que aquí me limitaba los carácteres a escribir. ¿Se os ocurre alguna solución? Me tiene loco... Mil gracias

Comment: Pero es que entonces lo estás poniendo a true donde no toca. Nosotros no tenemos acceso a tu proyecto, así que tienes que ver tú dónde modificar las cosas... deberías ponerla a true solo cuando realmente puedas recibir un nuevo click, si todavía no has refrescado la pantalla lo mismo no es el sitio correcto para cambiarla donde lo haces! Hazlo tras actualizar la información de la tabla

Comment: He probado a cambiar el flag en distintos sitios sin éxito. El problema, viene por el hecho de que si pulso una vez el programa hace el recorrido correctamente ya sea con el flag o sin él; pero cuando pulso dos veces, es como si el programa hiciera el recorrido una vez pero sin actualizar la información en pantalla, y saltando una segunda vez al evento gvDetalleFicheros_RowCommand de forma que como el programa ha pasado por todos los eventos el flag ya se ha cambiado. ¿Habría alguna forma de controlar/saber/detectar si se produce un evento por segunda vez? Gracias